# Implications when an input has the same name as another input's ID

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

The following script surprised me.  It produces the following results:

InternetExplore

> aaa: undefined    bbb: undefined    ccc: value3    ddd: value4    eee: value5

FireFox and Chrome

> aaa:    bbb:    ccc: value3    ddd: value4    eee: value5

Why when one input has the same ID as another input's name (or by reverse), the input doesn't have a value?

```js
function testResults(form) {
  alert([
    "aaa: " + form.aaa.value,
    "bbb: " + form.bbb.value,
    "ccc: " + form.ccc.value,
    "ddd: " + form.ddd.value,
    "eee: " + form.eee.value
  ].join(',    '));
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="aaa" id="bbb" value="value1" />
  <input type="text" name="bbb" id="aaa" value="value2" />
  <input type="text" name="ccc" id="ccc" value="value3" />
  <input type="text" name="ddd" value="value4" />
  <input type="text" id="eee" value="value5" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="testResults(this.form)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Wrong closure, like so often in JavaScript...

Comment: @kuroineko  Yea, I know, but the question relates to the conflict when one element has the same name as another elements ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm used when you access a form element by name or ID is defined in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-nameditem):

> When a `form` element is **indexed for named property retrieval**, the user
>   agent must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Let *candidates* be a live `RadioNodeList` object containing all the listed elements whose form owner is the `form` element that have either
>      an `id` attribute or a `name` attribute equal to *name*, with the exception
>      of `input` elements whose `type` attribute is in the Image Button state,
>      in tree order.
> 2. If *candidates* is empty, let *candidates* be a live `RadioNodeList` object containing all the `img` elements that are descendants of the
>      `form` element and that have either an `id` attribute or a `name` attribute
>      equal to *name*, in tree order.
> 3. If *candidates* is empty, *name* is the name of one of the entries in the `form` element's past names map: return the object associated with
>      *name* in that map.
> 4. If *candidates* contains more than one node, return *candidates* and abort these steps.
> 5. Otherwise, *candidates* contains exactly one node. Add a mapping from *name* to the node in *candidates* in the `form` element's past names map,
>      replacing the previous entry with the same name, if any.
> 6. Return the *node* in candidates.

Specifically, the problem is that there are two candidates for `form.aaa`, so it returns a [`RadioNodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#radionodelist) collection (step 4):

```js
form.aaa; // RadioNodeList [ <input#bbb>, <input#aaa> ]
form.aaa[0]; // <input#bbb>
form.aaa[1]; // <input#aaa>
```

For `form.eee` there is only one candidate, so it is returned instead (step 6):

```js
$0.eee; // <input#eee>
```

Comment: Additionally,  `form.aaa.value` should return the empty string, not undefined like IE. This is defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dom-radionodelist-value).

Comment: You mean IE is not doing it right?  Inconceivable!  So, I get from a specification and DOM perspective, ID or name do not have precedence over one another, and they are both just added to a collection.  Is there any best practice to use one over the other?

Comment: @user1032531 If you want to send the form, better use names. If you want to get the elements faster in JS (with getElementById) use IDs (you can use getElementsByName with names, though). A common approach is using both IDs and names, but the same string for each element.

Comment: Thank you Oriol. This was very helpful.  Typically, I use the same string for names and IDs, but good to know the implications! Also, thank you for editing my original post with that cool Run Code Snippet.  I will make a point of learning how to do so in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The DOM is weird...

But `querySelector` will let you get by name OR id. It's like the jQuery selector.

```
form.querySelector('[name=aaa]').value
form.querySelector('#aaa').value
```

The reason it doesn't have a value btw is because `form.aaa` tries to match by `id` or `name` and returns multiple elements. Trying to get the value of that returns `""`, or apparently `undefined` in IE

Comment: Thanks.  I was more interested on what was happening, but appreciate the tip on `querySelector` and will look into it.  Given my original code, `console.log(form.aaa)` displays a  RadioNodeList element?

Comment: Didn't originally notice your explanation of what was happening.  thanks